# Text hugging too close to image bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, margin, padding

I'm looking to create some "breathing space" for my image by adding about 5px of separation from the image to my text. 
Usually it is easily resolved with padding, margin or positioning, but not this time :( 
I tried replacing the p tags with dd's, dl's etc... but for some reason none of the techniques I tried have been fruitful. I am using bootstrap so I understand the pre-written code can be overwriting mine.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10" id="abouttext">
            <img  id="aboutphoto" src="../images/Micheal_morrison.jpg" class="col-sm-4 pull-left img-thumbnail img-responsive" alt="image"/>
            <h3>Doctor</h3>
            <p>dLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus</p>

            <h4>How does it work?</h4>
            <p>dLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus</p>

            <h4>Why Intuitive healing? </h4>
            <p>dLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus</p>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The css is a bit messy because I have been trying so many different ways but here it is as of now:

```
#p {
 padding-left: 50px;
 margin-left: 10px;
}

#aboutphoto {
 position: absolute;
 padding: 10px;
 margin: 10px;
}
abouttext.p {
  min-width: 450px;
  max-width: 650px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  }
```

Again, units are off but I was just looking for a result in my browser page.

Thank you so much in advance for your help!

Comment: You're missing a hash character on `abouttext` in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate a bit on what you are trying to do? You have put position: absolute on the image which will result in it being detached from the DOM hierarchy and placed above your text.

I've created a JSFiddle to put the image back in place using float: left and assume that's what you're trying to do. Otherwise please elaborate a bit on your expected result.

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/volzy/atx26f2z/

```
#aboutphoto {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Volzy, as things are, the image and the text are touching one another and it does not look good. I am trying to have some space between the image and the text, but padding and margins aren't helping me for some stranger reason

Answer (score 0):

You have everything in one div and this is causing you problems.

Try this:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3" id="abouttext">
        <img  id="aboutphoto" src="../images/Micheal_morrison.jpg" class="pull-left img-thumbnail img-responsive" alt="Dr.Michael Morrison"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7" id="abouttext">
        <h3>Doctor</h3>
        <p>dLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus</p>

        <h4>How does it work?</h4>
        <p>dLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus</p>

        <h4>Why Intuitive healing? </h4>
        <p>dLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

Here we have two div's and picture is separated nicely.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Goran!  This is looking better but for some reason it made the image very small, so i'm not sure the space happened because of the image size of because of the new div.... any suggestions? :)

Comment: on #aboutphoto change width of the picture. Try to put 80%. 
#aboutphoto {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 80%;
}
Play with the percentage of the width how it fits the best. And you don't need position:absolute I think

Comment: sorry I had not noticed that you have col-sm-4  in img tag. Just delete that and your image will be on her natural size. col-sm-4  is shrinking the picture. Then if you want you can adjust size of the picture with width in #aboutphoto. I edited this in my answer (deleted col-sm-4).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is your use of `posiiton:absolute`. (You also have `col-md-10` then `col-sm-4` nested within the `img` tag which isn't generally how this grid system works.)

See example.

```css
#aboutphoto {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px 20px 5px 0px;
}
#abouttext.p {
  min-width: 450px;
  max-width: 650px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 15px;
}
@media (max-width: 992px) {
  #aboutphoto {
    margin: 0 20px 5px 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" id="abouttext">
      <img id="aboutphoto" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="pull-left img-thumbnail img-responsive" alt="Dr" />
      <h3>Doctor</h3>

      <p>dLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus</p>
      <h4>How does it work?</h4>

      <p>dLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus</p>
      <h4>Why Intuitive healing? </h4>

      <p>dLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Vanburen for your help! When I ran you snipper it looked just as I wanted, however when I applied it to my code on my desktop, it didn't change a thing :( Could it be because of a different code that either Bootstrap or myself have written ?

Comment: Did you change your CSS and the column structure like in the example?

Comment: I doubt it matters much but which version of Bootstrap are you using just out of curiosity?

Comment: It has to be BS 3 because I just downloaded it 2 months ago

Comment: Honestly, it's hard to say then. Have you directly overwritten any Bootstrap classes?

Comment: What do you mean by "editable"? Are you using a theme/template?

Comment: Bootstrap has a core css file and a "custom" css file. Normally, you should only edit the custom file and leave the core file alone.

Comment: Right, the alternate file is the theme file if that's what you're referring to but that should not change any layout properties on it's own